# New props in functional components does not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently having a problem on my functional components that does not update when it receives new props. I want to clarify my mental model and after looking at the [cheat sheet](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) from react website, new props should update the component if it is saved in the state right?

Consider the following code:

```
const defaultStart = dayjs().startOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const defaultEnd = dayjs().endOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD");

function IncidentList({
  incidentsList,
  requestIncidents,
  selectedLoc,
  selectedLoc,
  startDate = defaultStart,
  endDate = defaultEnd,
}) {
  const [selectedEndDate, handleEndDateChange] = useState(endDate);
  const [selectedStartDate, handleStartDateChange] = useState(startDate);

  useEffect(() => {
  ┊ const payload = {
  ┊ ┊ location: selectedLoc,
  ┊ ┊ start_date: dayjs(selectedStartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  ┊ ┊ end_date: dayjs(selectedEndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  ┊ };
  ┊ requestIncidents(payload);
  }, [requestIncidents, selectedEndDate, selectedStartDate]);

   return (
   ┊ <div className="container sm:p-8 md:p-16">
   ┊ ┊ <MaterialTable
   ┊ ┊ ┊ columns={columns}
   ┊ ┊ ┊ data={incidentsList}
   ┊ ┊ ┊ title="Incident list"
   ┊ ┊ ┊ actions={actions}
   ┊ ┊ ┊ options={{
   ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ pageSize: 20,
   ┊ ┊ ┊ }} 
 ┊ ┊ ┊ components={{
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ Toolbar: (props) => (
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className="p-8">
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <MTableToolbar {...props} />
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className="ml-8 p-8 border-1 w-1/2">
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className="flex flex-row">
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <p className="text-lg font-semibold">Filter Using:</p>
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className="flex flex-row -mx-4">
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className="px-8">
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <DatePicker
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ format="YYYY-MM-DD"
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ label="Minimum Date"
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ inputVariant="outlined"
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ minDate={new Date("2015-01-01")}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ maxDate={dayjs().format()}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ value={selectedStartDate}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ onChange={handleStartDateChange}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ />
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className="px-8">
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <DatePicker
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ format="YYYY-MM-DD"
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ label="Maximum Date"
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ inputVariant="outlined"
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ minDate={selectedStartDate}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ maxDate={dayjs().format()}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ value={selectedEndDate}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ onChange={handleEndDateChange}
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ />
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
 ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ),
 ┊ ┊ ┊ }} />

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  incidentsList: state.incident.incidents,
  selectedLoc: state.loc.selectedLoc,
});

IncidentList.propTypes = {
  incidentsList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  requestIncidents: PropTypes.func,
  selectedLoc: PropTypes.number,
  endDate: PropTypes.string,
  startDate: PropTypes.string,
};
```

The code above does not update the state when I updated both `startDate` and `endDate`. I have to call `useEffect` for it to sync. I thought when we are receiving new props, a component should re-renders thus recalls `useState` to set it with the default value.

I want to know why do I have to add this code in order for it to work where I was expecting my component to update when I updated the props. Code added:

```
  useEffect(() => {
  ┊ if (startDate && endDate) {
  ┊ ┊ handleEndDateChange(endDate);
  ┊ ┊ handleStartDateChange(startDate);
  ┊ }
  }, [startDate, endDate]);
```

Comment: useEffect will be run when the variables in the []

it works like legacy `componentWillUpdate`

Comment: I know, the question is why doesn't it re-renders after I supply it with new props that I'm using as a default state @moficodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IncidentList` will re-render if any of it's props are updated.

However, it doesn't seem like you are using `startDate` and `endDate`. Instead, you're just setting the initial value of `selectedStartDate` and `selectedEndDate`, which is not part of the re-rendering, and thus `selectedStartDate` and `selectedEndDate` will not update when `startDate` and `endDate` update.

try using `startDate` and `endDate` directly, unless you have some logic (`if (startDate && endDate)` ??), in which case you'll need the state objects you added.

Comment: Sorry I actually used it in the components, I used the `selectedStartDate` and `selectedEndDate` in the component. However it doesn't update... Should I just use the props straightaway?

Comment: yeah just use them as they come. useState is for creating a local state object, and the function that updates it. if you need to use a prop anywhere in the compoentn, you can use it directly. when it updates, the component will update. if you use it inside useEffect, the useEffect will run (given that you added the prop into the dependency array)

Comment: Yeah you're right, If i used the props straightaway then it re-renders. I guess useState is just called as a constructor...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass props from parent's state.

For example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import IncidentList from './IncidentList';
const IncidentListContainer = () => {
   const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(new Date);
   const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(new Date);
   setStartDate(newDate); // this will update child
   return (
      <IncidentList 
         startDate={startDate}
         endDate={endDate}
         // other props
      />
   );
}
```

In contrast, the following won't work:

```js
const startDate = new Date;
const endDate = new Date;
changeDatesLater(startDate, endDate); // this won't work
const IncidentListContainer = () => {
   return (
      <IncidentList 
         startDate={startDate}
         endDate={endDate}
         // other props
      />
   );
}
```